# Is there a way to list all available routes in a Nancy application?

Tags: nancy

I'm implementing an API via a web service, using Nancy.

I'd like to have a /help or /docs page that programmatically lists all of the available routes, so that I can provide API users with automatically generated/updated documentation.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  (Inside a route handler, "this.routes" gives access to a collection of defined routes - but only on the current NancyModule. I'd need a programmatic way to list all registered routes, not just ones in the current module)

Comment: I answered this on the question you posted on our user group

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by taking a dependency on the IRouteCacheProvider and calling GetCache - we actually do this in one of our demos in the main repo:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Aspnet/MainModule.cs#L13

Comment: Link broken as of June 2016. This is the new location if I'm not mistaken: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/samples/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Aspnet/MainModule.cs

Answer (score 10):

Not exactly what you need, but there is also a built in dashboard panel in Nancy. To enable it do:

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override DiagnosticsConfiguration DiagnosticsConfiguration
    {
        get { return new DiagnosticsConfiguration { Password = @"secret"}; }
    }
}
```

And then you can access it on {yournancyapp}/_nancy

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Diagnostics

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to use `IRouteCacheProvider` like @grumpydev mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638833/196451):

```
// within your module
public class IndexModule : NancyModule
{
    // add dependency to IRouteCacheProvider
    public IndexModule(Nancy.Routing.IRouteCacheProvider rc)
    {
        routeCache = rc;
        Get["/"] = GetIndex;
    }

    private Nancy.Routing.IRouteCacheProvider routeCache;

    private dynamic GetIndex(dynamic arg)
    {
        var response = new IndexModel();

        // get the cached routes
        var cache = routeCache.GetCache();

        response.Routes = cache.Values.SelectMany(t => t.Select(t1 => t1.Item2));

        return response;
    }
}

public class IndexModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Nancy.Routing.RouteDescription> Routes { get; set; }
}
```

You can get the routing information like `Path` and `Method` from the list of `Nancy.Routing.RouteDescription`. For example with this view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Available routes:</p>
<table>
<thead><tr><th>URL</th><th>Method</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
@Each.Routes
<tr><td>@Current.Path</td><td>@Current.Method</td></tr>
@EndEach
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```